# Equation number position in a new line

Tags: equations, numbering

How do I put the number of each equation in the new line (not the same line with the equation, located in the next line on the right)

This is required for all the equations in my thesis (which I found very weird).
Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you want this...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox to \displaywidth{\hss\m@th\normalfont#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f\langle s,t \rangle = \sum_{\substack{v,w \in E \\ v \in S, w \in T}}f(v,w) \\    
\end{equation}

aaa
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much David, it works. I am not sure, but my boss is:-( This is so ugly. I don't understand why he wants the equations to be done this way. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't `\displaywidth` be better than `\textwidth`? I didn't test, though.

Comment: @egreg, yes, probably.

Answer (score 1):

Weird indeed. This should work:

```
\begin{align}
e^{i\pi} & = \cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi) = -1 \notag \\
  & \label{eq:whatever}
\end{align}
%
This is Equation \eqref{eq:whatever}
```

[image]